# protractor :don't wait for repeater elements to appears in Dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, testing, protractor

I do end to end test using protractor. I don't used Selenium WebDriver .I connected directly to charm browser. When I start up the test 2 errors occurred.the first one:

> conFusion App E2E Testing menu 0 item should show the number of comments as
>     Message:
>       Expected 0 to equal 5.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Failed expectation

the second one:

> conFusion App E2E Testing menu 0 item should show the first comment author as
>     Message:
>       Failed: No element found using locator: by.model("FiltText")
>     Stack:

I used JSON  server  serve up the REST API for accessing the JSON data by my Angular application.there are five comments and filter to order the comments.
also I used gulp to serve up the Angular application. When I type in a  terminal gulp watch every-things worked right.but protractor is failed.

How can I make the protractor wait until element appears in the DOM?

the corresponding protractor configuration code is :

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout:11000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
     ],
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/',

   framework: 'jasmine',
   directConnect: true,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
     showColors: true,
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

scenarios.js code that contain e2e test

```
describe('menu 0 item', function() {
   beforeEach(function() {

     browser.get('index.html#/menu/0');


   });

   it('should have a name', function() {
   var name = element(by.binding('dish.name'));
   expect(name.getText()).
     toEqual('Uthapizza Hot $4.99');
 });

 it('should show the number of comments as', function() {

      expect(element.all(by.repeater('comment in dish.comments'))
       .count()).toEqual(5);


  });

   it('should show the first comment author as', function() {
      element(by.model('FiltText')).sendKeys('author');

     expect(element.all(by.repeater('comment in dish.comments'))
      .count()).toEqual(5);

    var author = element.all(by.repeater('comment in dish.comments'))
              .first().element(by.binding('comment.author'));

   expect(author.getText()).toContain('25 Cent');

 }); 
 });
```

The  partial code of Html page that I want to test :

```
<h4> Customer Comments &nbsp; 
                <span style="font-size:15px;">sorted by:<input type="text" ng-model="FiltText"></span></h4><blockquote ng-repeat="commet in dish.comments |orderBy:FiltText">
         <h5>{{commet.rating}} Stars</h5>
         <h5>{{commet.comment}}</h5>
         <footer>{{commet.author}}, <span>{{commet.date|date}}</span>. </footer>

            </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf or presenceOf() methods for waiting until element visible on UI or present in DOM. Follow the below code:

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var targetEle=element(locator);

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetEle),10000,'NOT VISIBLE'); //wait until 
//ele visible
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(targetEle),10000,'NOT PRESENT');//wait until 
//present in dom
```

Comment: is ExpectedConditions provided by Selenium WebDriver? because I don't used  Selenium WebDriver .I .I connected directly to charm browser.

Comment: could you plz specifically determine where should I put ExpectedConditions method in my code? I'm new in protractor

Comment: I did what you suggest but it show me this message :  Failed: NOT VISIBLE
    Wait timed out after 10009ms

Comment: why this is happing? how can lockers are not visible?